# Compare different rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Section (id, origin, destination, departure_time, arrival_time)
1 - city1 - city2 - 2017-01-01 10:00:00 - 2017-01-01 12:00:00
2 - city2 - city3 - 2017-01-01 12:00:00 - 2017-01-01 13:00:00
3 - city3 - city4 - 2017-01-01 13:00:00 - 2017-01-01 15:00:00
4 - city4 - city5 - 2017-01-01 15:00:00 - 2017-01-01 16:30:00 

Trip_Section(trip_id, section_id)
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
1 - 4

Trip(id, from, to, departure_time)
1 - city1 - city5 - 2017-01-01 10:00:00
```

Table sections contains all stops of a trip, and i need search all trips that contains an origin and destination requested.
In this part i'm trying to recover the trips with the parameters in different sections.
For example: i want to travel from city2 to city4
so my query is:

```
select ts.trip_id, count(ts.trip_id) >= 2 from Section as s 
inner join Trip_Section ts on ts.sections_id = s.id
where (s.origin = 'city2' OR s.destination = 'city4')
GROUP BY ts.trip_id having count(ts.trip_id) >= 2;
```

and the result is correct, but if i search from city4 to city2, the result is not empty, is the same than the first case.

How can i compare the different rows to return only the rows when the departure_time of origin will be smaller than departure_time of destination (or another posibility is check the id of destination is greater than id of origin).
Can someone help me?

Comment: "and the result is correct" - How is that possible with the syntax error in the query? You probably mean `OR s.destination = 'city4'`.

Comment: AND s.arrival_time > s.departure_time ?

Comment: I don't understand -- you don't show columns named `origin_id` or `destination_id` in your data model -- how does this sql run at all?

Answer (score 0):

- Find the section with `origin = 'city2'`
- Find the Trip for that section
- Find the section from the same trip with `destionation='city4'`
- Find all sections from that trip between the two sections above

All in one query:

```
select tso.trip_id, s.*
from Section so
join Trip_Section tso on tso.section_id = so.id
join Trip_Section tsd on tsd.trip_id = tso.trip_id
join Section sd       on sd.id = tsd.section_id
join Trip_Section ts  on ts.trip_id = tso.trip_id
join Section s        on s.id = ts.section_id
where so.origin      = 'city1'
  and sd.destination = 'city4'
  and so.departure_time <= sd.departure_time
  and s.departure_time  >= so.departure_time
  and s.departure_time  <= sd.departure_time
```

This will give you an overview of all stops between two cities per trip.

If you don't need all stops you can also try this one:

```
select tso.trip_id, so.origin, so.departure_time, sd.destination, sd.arrival_time
from Section so
join Trip_Section tso on tso.section_id = so.id
join Trip_Section tsd on tsd.trip_id = tso.trip_id
join Section sd       on sd.id = tsd.section_id
where so.origin      = 'city2'
  and sd.destination = 'city4'
  and so.departure_time <= sd.departure_time
```

http://rextester.com/XUOYS38451

Comment: Though it's not exactly what you asked for. But this way you have an overview with all stops between two cities.

Comment: I need just the Trips, not the sections, but i'm working on that. thank you!

Comment: @NicoLucini you can take the second query, join it with the `Trip` table on `trip_id` and select only columns from that table.

Comment: yes, i tried that, but i need to fix some on this query, because is not working in another cases. Here is one example:
http://rextester.com/edit/GGPHT16173

Comment: i created more sections and cities in the example, and i searched from city2 to city6 and it should be returns 1 result, and actually returns 4 trips

Comment: I think i found the error, in this line "join Trip_Section tsd on tsd.trip_id = tsd.trip_id" one of tsd.trip_id should be tso.trip_id